# What is the topological equivalence of a genus 2 torus?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Am I get really stuck, or it is not obvious: what is the topological equivalence of a genus 2 torus?

We know torus is $S^1 \times S^1$. Then how about genus 2?

Thank you~

Comment: What is a "*topological equivalence*"? (Do you mean "***equivalent***"? Though even if that's what you meant, it's still not a standard term.)

Comment: Er.. May be it is not the right way to put it. Like torus = $S^1 \times S^1$.. Thank you @ZevChonoles

Comment: "A genus 2 torus" is a contradiction in terms: a surface can be genus 2 or can be a torus, but not both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like maybe you want
$$(S^1\times S^1)\mathbin{\#} (S^1\times S^1)$$
as an answer, where $\#$ is [the "connected sum" operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_sum)?

Comment: Exactly.... So genus 2 torus is $(S^1 \times S^1) \# (S^1 \times S^1)$? And what is the right way to ask...?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you're just asking how to write "genus-2 torus" in symbols, while **not** using the actual symbolic name (the symbol used to denote a torus would normally be $T^2$ or $\mathbb{T}^2$; and for a $g$-holed torus for $g>1$, $\Sigma_g$ is a common notation I've seen). I can't think of any word that describes your question (though "topological equivalence" is definitely not a good one). I see it as equivalent to asking "*What is the \_\_\_ of squaring?*" with the desired answer being "$x\times x$" instead of "$x^2$".